# Does 'known as' have to mean 'in the spec'?

Tags: discussion

See my answer to the following question: [Arrow functions vs Fat arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588722/arrow-functions-vs-fat-arrow-functions)

When quoting the tag wiki to point out that they were the same thing as far as JS goes, I got a bit of grief over the fact that the term "fat arrows" 'is obsolete' and so it is incorrect to state that arrow functions are "also known as fat arrow functions" .

My opinion is that the very existence of the question shows that they are also know as 'fat arrow functions', and that 'known as' does not imply any official sanction, just fact. What is the consensus of the community?

Comment: You learned something new.  Q+A is a two-way street.  If you equate that to "grief" then you are probably not going to enjoy contributing to SO much.

Comment: @HansPassant did you see the comments aimed at me before they were deleted?

Comment: I didn't - what did they say? Also reaching a consensus on something like this might be difficult. Some will be staunchly on your side, some staunchly against - and I suspect the majority won't care enough to make a choice

Comment: @Clive [Here are the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzEsW.png).

Comment: If you feel that the term "known as" is being interpreted differently from your intentions, then consider using different terminology so that your meaning isn't ambiguous and open to misinterpretation.

Comment: Yes, I saw them.  They were, erm, passionate.  That's pretty normal as well, SO users don't like bad or incorrect answers all that much.  Who does.

Comment: Eh? That's not "grief", that's a conversation. One that you clearly didn't like the content of, but a conversation sans grief, nonetheless. The argument is also quite compelling: you're using an obsolete term from an obsolete source, which refers mainly to a technology that the question wasn't even asking about...

Comment: @Clive if no consensus is reached, so be it. If the consensus goes against me, I can always add that as a note to my answer. If people agree with mean I can leave as is.

Comment: Oh ok, that last comment was unnecessary, will definitely give you that :) But the sentiment seems sound to me

Comment: @clive "My goodness, what a hard head we have. It's quite amazing that you would continue to push ideas you obviously have no knowledge about, and quote sources you have no ability to judge the accuracy of based on your own expertise." is not grief? Looks quite personal to me...

Comment: Yeah missed that last comment, that's a lot nearer "grief", sure. You don't have to put up with insults, flag it and forget it. But the rest of the comments seem spot on to me, and haven't really been addressed

Comment: @Clive if you agree with his position, put an answer here agreeing with his position. As I said, if that gets support I'll amend my answer to something along the lines of 'incorrectly known as'

Comment: I'm happy just commenting to get clarification on your position. You don't think your answer was obsolete and mainly related to a technology that the question wasn't about? (Question was about JavaScript, specifically es2016, your answer referred mainly to coffee script)

Comment: @clive The question was about JS arrow functions (no coffeescript tag), and fat arrow functions, noted they were the same, and asked if there was a difference. I answered by quoting the tag wiki and bolding that arrow functions in JS are also known as fat arrow functions, thus trying to both answer the question (there is no difference) and give a pointer to how the questioner could have checked the tag wiki. The only possible thing that could be wrong with my answer is if the 'known as' means in the spec, as opposed to more generally 'known as'

Comment: I disagree - if the question didn't specifically mention coffeescript, I can't understand why quoting something that talks mostly about coffeescript would be an acceptable way to answer. The fact it's in a tag wiki is irrelevant, you still need to make sure any source is accurate and relevant before quoting it (or more to the point, before expecting people will agree with it). All that aside, "known as" surely needs to have its root in something official, or by definition the question is just asking for opinions, right?

Comment: @Clive the crux of the answer was "while JavaScript has only the latter, which are also known as "fat arrow functions"." I think that's very reasonable answer to the question.

Comment: @Clive "All that aside, "known as" surely needs to have its root in something official" Why? I don't see why facts should be ignored just because it's not official. Note that the whole question arose in the first place due to the wide use of the term.

Comment: To me it reads "this is what coffeescript does, and by the way JavaScript started using the same term for something recently too". Which makes it basically irrelevant to me, a JS developer who does use ES2016, but doesn't use coffeescript (i.e. The sort of person who would naturally land on that question via tags). That's just me though, we're obviously not going to agree on this so let's leave it there

Comment: If there's nothing official, in what way is it a "fact"?

Comment: @clive I'm actually happy to clear that bit up (that isn't the 'known as' problem though). Regarding "If there's nothing official, in what way is it a "fact"?", I can only say that usage is fact as opposed to spec. And thanks for taking the time to discuss.

Comment: @Servy interesting point, and potentially good advice when crafting an answer from scratch, but in this case I was quoting something else.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Doesn't change the point.  If you're quoting something that people are misinterpreting than don't quote that thing; paraphrase it and use terminology that's clearer, or find a clearer source to quote.  Or in this case, since the source is a wiki, you can just edit the source to be clearer, as has since been done.

Comment: @Servy To be honest, I'm personally flabbergasted that it was interpreted that way, hence the question here to see if people do interpret it that way.

Comment: I don't think it *has* to mean per the spec but it's not outlandish that it would be read that way. That said, I'd think a simple clarification that "known as" is referring to common usage, not the spec, should have been sufficient. Not something that should have gone on more than 2 comments, much less resulting in insults.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not interested in the coffeescript issue, but I think "known as" is stating a fact about *the English language*, which has no formal process for deprecation or obsolescence. [Corpus-based linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_linguistics) is the tool for deciding whether a statement is correct, and it doesn't always yield a definitive answer.

I think all of these are true statements, in spite the tendency of certain people to get riled up upon reading them:

1. In RS-232 serial communications, the common 9-pin connector is/was **known as** a "DB-9".
2. In C, the cast operator is also **known as** a "typecast".
3. In almost any context, a collection of 1,048,576 bytes is **known as** a "megabyte".

People wanting to avoid the use of a word or phrase they don't like should offer a better argument than "it's not in the holy text". Especially when they're arguing against explicitly telling people the truth about the relationship between the formal terminology they'll read here and some informal terms they'll find elsewhere.